# Rooting the Karbonn smart tab 7

Tags: rooting, karbonn-smart-tab-7

First of all, I understand that similar questions have been asked trillions of times before. But, as I've come to learn, not this specific one. So, here I go...

I recently bought a Karbonn smart tab 7 and upgraded it to android 4.0.3. I've been using it a lot, and it has'nt given me any problems so far[Except the annoying settings reset, which is a question for another day]. I want to root my device and have tried various tutorials and NOTHING worked. Whenever I try to use an application to this, it tells me that the device cannot be found. I have connected it to the computer via the USB cable and Enabled usb debugging and even tried enabling mass storage mode[Only the SD card's file structure showed up in My computer]. I read somewhere that I would need to download some drivers for this to work, but am not able to find any drivers. I have also tried talking to customer care about the drivers, and they just farted on me.

P.s. I have posted this question on a few forums before here[I did'nt know Stackexchange hav a site for Android!!!] and they eiter closed the question and voted me down or no one replied. Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have succeeded in rooting the Karbonn Smart Tab 7 and am apparently the first person on the net to do so. In your face, Karbonn Technical Department. I have been using it only for a few hours now, and it is working fine (EDIT: I've been using it for 4 months now and it still works fine :) - August '13).

Here are the steps for any other wanderer in the same plight as I was:

1. The first step is a warning to all users. Please be aware of the consequences of rooting before doing so. It should work perfectly, but just to be on the safe side, back up all your data.
2. Connect the tab to the computer and enable mass storage mode. Also keep in mind that the Karbonn Smart Tab 7 has internal memory and an internal storage card. The internal one cannot be used for the purpose of rooting. You need to put in an external microSD card. When you connect the device in mass storage mode, the internal SD card's name will probably be NOVO7.
3. Download [this file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/vlabh9m9lc8mfpq/Crystal_Root.zip) and put it in the root of the external microSD.
4. Put the tab in recovery mode. For those of you who don't know how to do this, switch off the device and hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> and <kbd>power</kbd> buttons till it says "android is upgrading...", and then release the <kbd>power</kbd> button but keep holding the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button.
5. Click on "Apply update from SD card" and select "crystal_root.zip". It should install.
6. Now reboot it and it's done!!!
7. You can check if the rooting process has been successful by downloading the [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) app from the Play Store. The app is (obviously) used to check if the root is accessible. You will also find that the [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) app has been installed automatically.

Enjoy!!!

P.s. Please vote me up (I would love that) and also thanks to @[Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) for giving me a heads up on how this stuff works.

Comment: Glad you made it, Hele -- congrats! Though I cannot verify (as I do not have the device), +1 from me for the detailed instructions! I took the freedom to improve formatting, added a few links, and updated my answer as well to point out the different devices. I also updated the "link on top" for you, as you currently lack the rep for that :)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Edit:** As it turned out, the "A7" and "Smart tab 7" are two different devices. These are the instructions for the "A7" -- for the "Smart Tab 7", please refer to [Hele's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41735/16575).</sup>

Instructions for the A7 can be found e.g. at [this XDA-developers post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=29149445&postcount=2):

1. Download the ROM from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?q2l05s73iz4qedv)
2. Copy the downloaded `update.zip` file to the root of the memory card and then insert the memory card into the phone.
3. Power off the phone (note the battery should be kept above 50%) press and hold up the <kbd>volume+</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> sources (the latter obviously refers to the <kbd>Power</kbd> button)
4. Continue holding until the recovery screen appears red, then let go
5. Select apply update from sdcard (in the recovery screen, use the <kbd>volume up</kbd> key up to move up and down, press and hold the <kbd>power</kbd> key to select)
6. Select the file `update.zip`
7. Wait until your ROM file gets installed
8. When the machine has completed installing ROM file, it returns to the recovery menu. Select "Reboot system now".

The XDA-Post also contains two links to other documents, in case this one fails.

Comment: I've done the jailbreaking process tens of times, but none rooting. I have already been to the site u referred me to. My device is a Karbonn smart tab 7, not a7. In case this method does'nt work, it'll harm my device right?

Comment: The link is broken. Please fix.

Comment: Hele, the link to XDA is not broken. Please check there. If the other link is broken: Sorry, I cannot do all the research for you. If you can tell me a replacement, I will fix it in. I only transferred an extract of that XDA article here for your convenience -- I don't have this device myself. // As for the previous comment: Usually it either works or not. If things get messed up, a factory-reset usually fixes this. I cannot guarantee anything, though...

Comment: I found the way, but thanks for the help @Izzy ! :)