# How to Increase RAM in my karbonn s2

Tags: ram, karbonn-smart-tab-7

my karbonn s2 has 512 MB RAM but it is always shows 85 % full I have installed RAM cleaner app but not happy with it. sometimes my phone hang down. what can be done to increase the memory (RAM) ?

Comment: Free RAM is a bad sign. See: [0 ram free on ICS](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36828/16575), and also [Are there guidelines on how much free RAM a phone should have - specifically Samsung Galaxy S?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20032/16575) / [Can you upgrade the RAM of an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22997/16575)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are not considering adding more physical RAM to your phone, because it is not possibly at least not safely!

1. You could try and remove applications you dont use, many of them have background services running.
2. Disable live wallpapers if any!
3. Root your phone and remove all bloatware.

Install a light launcher on your phone and see how that works out!

Link for rooting instructions : [Root](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41735/6204)